# A New idea in the old Marshall attack?

Tags: opening, ruy-lopez, novelties

I was recently playing around with the
game Capablanca vs Marshall (1918,new York) where Marshall unveiled his legendary attack, but with 12...Nf6?! (The dubious mark has been attached to this move ever since 12...c6 was found)

But checking the position with SF 16 on lichess, at around depth 45, I found a probably untouched approach with black,now after 13) D4, black can play, 13... C5!?

I was wondering if anyone has any more knowledge or understanding of this position, because at least on lichess database, C5 is a novelty.

Also worth noting is that the engine evaluated the modern main line with c6 as giving an advantage of around 0.3 to white while the old line leads to an advantage of 0.5, so there's definitely something to this line.

What even is black's compensation here though, because there's no clear attack brewing after c5?

Comment: Please include a chessboard and highlight all different variants, otherwise it hard to follow.

Comment: @Don, how does one do that?